# Animating an image drawn with CGContextDrawImage

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Is it possible to animate an image in the current graphics content if it was rendered using `CGContextDrawImage`?

I need the effects of blend modes but also with animation options.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: How about subclassing `UIView`, implementing `drawRect:` and animating through `animateWithDuration:...` methods? Performance might be bad though.

Comment: I cannot get the blend modes using this. I need to have 3 UIImageViews on top of one another, and their pixels should be combined to create the resulting pixel at each point. The blend modes offer this, but it is on a context only. I need to have animations on UIImageViews and the blend modes too.

Comment: For a quick and dirty approach, you can just create 3 UIImageView objects and stack the up in the view, then the composite operation is done at runtime in the way you expect.